# The use of Theis equation based on time

Tags: fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, hydraulics, geotechnical-engineering

The storage coefficient (s) for artesian basin can be determined by the following equation (Theis equation):

$$s=\frac{Q}{4\pi T}\int_{\frac{r^2S}{4Tt}}^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du$$

Does this equation work for confined aquifers with an arbitrary *t* or there are some limits for time (t) to be used in this equation?